# Растягивается иконка на канвасе

Tags: android, android-canvas

Реализовал возможность удаления и редактирования элемента в RecyclerView при помощи свайпа. Но осталась проблема отображения иконки на канвасе. В зависимости от ширины айтема иконка растягивается а мне нужно чтобы ее размер не менялся.

`Функция отрисовки:`

```
     fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, rect: RectF, pos: Int) {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = color
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)

        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId)

        drawable?.setBounds(
            rect.left.toInt().plus(drawable.intrinsicWidth).plus(30),
            rect.top.toInt().plus(drawable.intrinsicHeight * 2).plus(30),
            rect.right.toInt().minus(drawable.intrinsicWidth).minus(30),
            rect.bottom.toInt().minus(drawable.intrinsicHeight * 2).minus(30)
        )
        drawable?.draw(canvas)

        clickRegion = rect
        this.pos = pos
    }
```

Какие значения надо задать в drawable.setBounds чтобы иконку не растягивало в разные стороны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было из ширины rect вычесть ширину иконки и разделить на 2. И так же с высотой:

```
drawable?.setBounds(
            rect.left.toInt().plus((rect.width() - drawable.intrinsicWidth).toInt() / 2),
            rect.top.toInt().plus((rect.height() - drawable.intrinsicHeight).toInt() / 2),
            rect.right.toInt().minus((rect.width() - drawable.intrinsicWidth).toInt() / 2),
            rect.bottom.toInt().minus((rect.height() - drawable.intrinsicHeight).toInt() / 2)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете атрибут `intrinsicHeight`, следовательно отталкиваетесь от высоты родительского элемента. Чтобы её не учитывать, как в Вашем случае, нужно заменить этот атрибут на `height`.